# R TIME over 24 Hours

Tags: r

Data is:

`A = 29.`
`B = 30.`
`C = 2.`

How can I get D to return a time format like 29:30:02?

The `chron` function returns an error because time cannot go over 24 hours, but it's time elapsed.

I've tried using different functions and packages such as `chron`, `lubridate`, or `asPOXlt` but can't figure it out. Please help.

Right now, I think that I might make an if else statement. If value < 9, then paste 0.

Thank you.

Comment: Using `lubridate`'s `Period` class, `hours(29) + minutes(30) + seconds(2)`. How well this will work for you depends mostly on what you want to *do* with it.